# Getting started as Oracle Student

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle19c, oracle18c

I've starting to learn SQL and heavily interested in learning Oracle. I'm trying to download a version of Oracle to help with hands-on learning, and wondering if I should learn from the Express 18c version or 19c. I notice a lot of the courses on Udemy are Oracle Database is version 12c. I'm wondering if it matters? As far as I can tell the Oracle website does not allow a download of 12c anymore (though I might have just missed it), and Exam 1Z0-071 seems to be more conceptual of an exam. However, I'd like to make the best choice for future, more detailed and in-depth learning as well

Comment: The version does not matter at all - at least not as long as you are a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [18c XE](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html) (or even 11gXE; it is still available). (You're right, 12c is unavailable.)

Express Edition (XE) is a good choice for students because it is easily installed and ready to go. As you don't plan to follow the DBA path (at least, that's how I understood what you said) and don't need to understand installation *tricks* in depth, something that installs in a matter of a few NEXT clicks is just a *plus*.

Alternatively, if you don't want to install anything, you can get a free account on [apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/en/). It is primarily used for Apex developers, but - you can still practice your (PL/)SQL skills in its SQL Workshop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!